# Configure AWS to allow for regular FTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, amazon-ec2, sftp

I am running a wordpress site within EC2.  Some of the plugins I am attempting to use are requiring my server credentials.  I can only SSH into my server right now using my .pem key.  I can also use this key and logon through port 22 with filezilla to achieve an SFTP experience.  However, there are no "FTP Users" configured.

Within the security group, I can open port 23, but I am unsure of where to setup users (or how).  Is this something that's done within apache, or the aws console?  And from there, could someone provide documentation on how to setup FTP accounts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress, you can actually enable direct install. The webserver user needs permission to write to wp-content. You may also need to enable a flag in your wp-config.php file in some cases as well.

`define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`

So if you want to enable FTP access, you need to first start by installing an FTP server. Depending on the AMI you used, you may or may not have one already installed.

The only caveat is that due to how networking is configured in EC2, you can only configure the server to run in passive mode. This configuration varies by the ftp server you choose to use.

Comment: what are some examples of ftp servers i could use with ec2? i'd like to look them up and try them out.  i'm not really looking for a workaround, i'm looking to straight up enable ftp, as it will make my life a whole lot easier.  i'd rather do this once, then have to go through a bunch of hoops everytime i want to do something.

Answer (score 0):

The **SSH SFTP Updater Support** plugin works well for running Wordpress on EC2. After installing, whenever you go to install/update a plugin, it will prompt you to enter your credentials each time.

1. For "Hostname" enter your domain name or IP address.
2. Enter your "FTP/SSH Username" ("ec2-user" or custom).
3. Do NOT enter any "FTP/SSH Password".
4. Either copy and paste your pem key into the dialogue window, or the easier solution, upload your pem key with "Upload Private Key" button. The plugin will require you to re-upload your pem key each time, and it will not store it.
5. For "Connection Type", click the "SSH2" radio button.

EC2 can change your permissions on folders (for security), so if ever the plugin says that it failed to install/update, the likely solution is to use FTP to loosen permissions on your plugin folder, such as to 755.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see this as a somewhat insecure way to store a private key. Unless you also lock this down to a user with no sudo access.

Comment: Are your referring to step 4, uploading the private key? The plugin requires you to upload your key each time you need to install/update a  plugin. So, the pem key is never stored in your Wordpress installation, and thus is not accessible to anyone unless they are logged into your computer. So it functions essentially the same as using a pem key on ssh. I can see where this was not clear from my original answer, so I have edited it.